# Solving a hyperbolic trigonometric function

Tags: equation-solving

How do I solve the following equation?

$\qquad (λ1^2+λ2^2)\sinh[λ1]\sinh[λ2]+2λ1λ2(1-\cosh[λ1]\cosh[λ2])=0,$

I saw in a paper that the Mathematica `FindRoot` function will give the solution. Can anyone tells me how to solve this equation using Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Can you write what exactly you are trying to solve for? Lambda1 or Lambda2 ? What have you tried with Mathematica till now?

Comment: I am solving free vibration of a beam with an axial force having fixed-fixed boundary conditions. The  Lambda1 and Lambda2 are roots of the auxiliary equation of ODE.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions are more readily found graphically.

```
ContourPlot[(λ1^2 + λ2^2) Sinh[λ1] Sinh[λ2] + 
   2 λ1*λ2 (1 - Cosh[λ1] Cosh[λ2]) == 0,
 {λ1, -10, 10}, {λ2, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The solutions appear to be `{λ2 = λ1, λ2 = -λ1, λ1 = 0, λ2 = 0}`. Verifying,

```
(λ1^2 + λ2^2) Sinh[λ1] Sinh[λ2] + 
    2 λ1*λ2 (1 - Cosh[λ1] Cosh[λ2]) == 0 /.
  {{λ2 -> λ1}, {λ2 -> -λ1}, {λ1 -> 0}, {λ2 -> 0}} // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

**EDIT:** As an alternative, verify the solutions by using each as an assumption to [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html)

```
Simplify[(λ1^2 + λ2^2) Sinh[λ1] Sinh[λ2] + 
     2 λ1*λ2 (1 - Cosh[λ1] Cosh[λ2]) == 0, Assumptions -> #] & /@
 {λ2 == λ1, λ2 == -λ1, λ1 == 0, λ2 == 0}

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you M.r. Bob Hanlon.  I am a beginner to Mathematica. Can you explain the coding and output plot?

Comment: [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)  shows  the `{λ1, λ2}` points (four lines) that satisfy the equation. The lines appear to correspond to `{λ2 = λ1, λ2 = -λ1, λ1 = 0, λ2 = 0}`. That these are in fact the solutions is verified by plugging each of these conditions into the equation using [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) with the corresponding [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html). If you don't understand a function or operator, highlight it in Mathematica and press `F1` for help.

Comment: Thanks a lot M.r. Bob Hanlon